# what does "output popen() streams are fully bufered by default" mean?

Tags: c, linux, file-io

According to `man popen`, "output popen() streams are fully bufered by default". But for the following code, i can still get all the information of my `ls -l` command, without the `fflush(p)` command. Does that make sence? I thought I would need the `fflush(p)` to flush the command's output that are stored in the user buffer, to the std out.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *p=popen("ls -l","r");
   char buf[100];
   memset(buf,0x00,100);
   //fflush(p);

   fread(buf,sizeof(char),90,p);

   printf("%s",buf);
   pclose(p);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an input `popen()` stream, not an output stream.

The `fflush()` function only operates on output or update streams, not input streams.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: @R..: I'm not sure how to expand this into an answer, then.  The asker is confused because `fflush()` is not necessary for an apparently buffered stream.  It's like a missing semicolon—it doesn't provoke a detailed answer, because there are no details to add.

Comment: @DietrichEpp you are right, it should be the input(to father process)

Comment: Well the title of the question is in question form, and that could be part of an answer. It would certainly help someone wondering about the same thing (without OP's mix-up of input/output) who stumbles across the question. But it's not a big deal.